# Lucene 6 typeahead

Tags: java, lucene

So I have a task to make some kind of type-ahead using Lucene 6.
Basic requirements:

- Queries should match partial words, not whole tokens. If I have "sum of sales" string indexed then query "sum of sa" should match.
- Relevancy should come out of the box or be easy to implement. Matches from start of the indexed string should have higher score that ones with match in the middle. Full match has highest score. Etc.

So far i've tried:

- PhraseQuery which has acceptable relevancy from out of the box, but does not match partial words.
- Combining PhraseQuery for all words in query and WildcardQuery for last(possibly incomplete word) using BooleanQuery. This will match those two parts in any order. So isn't good for me.
- Indexing separate copy of a field without tokenizing and using PrefixQuery and WildcardQuery. They don't give scoring I would like to have from out of the box.

Is there any approach I missed that could save my day and possibly next week?

Comment: i think in most of the cases approach number 2 should be OK, also I'm curious, if you could share examples, where this behavior (any order of tokens) could return false positive results

Comment: also, what's exactly wrong with approach 3?

Comment: But I explained what's wrong...

Comment: I'll try again. Second approach will match last part(wildcard) even if it happened in text BEFORE other terms(parts of phrase). And I need all terms to be matched in order.

Comment: Third case is not giving me any useful scoring. Consider two strings *test string* and *test string zero*. If I search with PrefixQuery for *test string* I'll get both documents with those strings and each will have score=1. That is order they will be returned to me will most likely to be an order of adding to index. But I expect full match to be more relevant that partial(have higher score).

Comment: cmon man:) They don't give scoring I would like to have from out of the box.
It's very broad, imho, so I asked what exactly you want or what exactly is wrong

Comment: about 2nd, I got the idea what's wrong here, but im curious what is real life use cases (if you could share it), when reverse order will give you false positive matches

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132782/discussion-between-aleksandr-kravets-and-mysterion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution - if you're using approach number 3, you could get proper scoring by setting RewriteMethod for **MultiTermQuery** (both *PrefixQuery* and *WildcardQuery* are sub-classes of *MultiTermQuery*)

```
MultiTermQuery query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("field1", "sum of sa*"));
            query.setRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE);
```

Possible problem with this method, that it could hit *BooleanQuery.TooManyClauses* exception, than you will need to implement your proper RewriteMethod, which will somehow preserve performance of constant scoring solution and incorporates the power of scoring.

Comment: On my test data this approach gives same result as plain wildcard/prefix query. What changed is scoring formula and corresponding score values. But for my sample data they stay identical. E.g. without rewrite score of each result is 1.0 and with rewrite 1.39. Doesn't help much :(. But projects' part I was working on is temporarily suspended. So I'll accept this answer and award bonus. Before suspension I ended up with MultiPhraseQuery with all words of query except the last one and manually enumerating all terms that start with last word of the query text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the proposed solutions meet performance requirements of a typeahead, moreover there is a best practice with [EdgeNGramTokenFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/EdgeNGramTokenFilter.html). 
Such filter will tokenizes the input:

> sum of sales

to

> s u m o f s a l e s

An example of filter to use would be:

```
new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(result, Side.FRONT, 1, 20);
```

Where result is your TokenStream input, Side.FRONT starts chopping from the start of the input, 1 is the character of the input you'll start chopping and 20 is the maximum.
There is plenty of more detailed examples around and this is the solution you want to use for your typeAhead.

Comment: it could be the case, but do not forget to mention that that is potentially faster solution but by using additional space for indexing.

Comment: It's true that additional space is required at indexing time, however I would say that the solution is definitively faster (not potentially) also the use of WildCards is normally discouraged in queries ran often and this is the case for typeAhead.

Comment: yeah, if disk space will be so huge, that you would need to read it from disk everytime.

Comment: @Mysterion define huge. The one that you mentioned is an edge case. If the user will get to such a big index, then the solution itself is wrong and would be necessary to move to a solution like Solr or ElasticSearch in order to avoid suffering of performance degradation. Wild card queries are so expensive that in production environment are normally blocked. I can tell you that on a 170GB lucene test index, type ahead with EdgeNgramTokenFilter is still performing very well.

Comment: i do not want to be offensive, just try to stay balanced, instead of going into black-white world (what is faster, etc. it's like saying Ferrari is faster then tank). I worked with index of 1 Tb (we cleaned it a lot) on ES and that's huge, I think. Nonetheless edgengram could be a solution for sure

Comment: Sure, that's big and you used Elastic Search as I was pointing out. We're trying to be constructive and I was just saying my opinion. Truth is that we'd need some benchmarks and tests to get to the truth. Also are we using just a Lucene index as stated in the question or Solr/ES? Maybe @AleksandrKravets can do it as part of his tasks and let us know.

Comment: @AR1,@Mysterion Using just Lucene, embedded in an application and running on top of RAMDirectory. In my current activity I'm handling small amounts of data.  Couple hundreds megabytes index size at most. I don't expect index to be huge as those you mentioned

Comment: @AlexsandrKravets then I think that EdgeNGramTokenFIlter is the way to go as index size it's not an issue. If your'e not sure just implement the two solutions proposed and check performance.